# Is there a media player that allows me to group together radio streams which are just mirrors of the same station?

Tags: mp3, music, streaming, media-player, amarok

I find it really annoying that for some radio stations, which have two or more servers to cope with the network load, there is not one single entry in amaroks playlist but two or more entries.

This makes it hard to pick the radio station from the list I like to listen to because all the entries are always shown with the last played track as name, and even if I only have a few radio stations in my list there will eventually be many different entries. And, if I use the keyboard shortcuts to navigate the playlist I always have to remember that radio station X has for example four entries in the playlist, so I have to press the shortcut for switching tracks four times to actually switch to the next station.

Now, ideally I would like some solution for amarok, but if someone knows of another media player that does this or something I would appreciate that information as well.

EDIT: I should probably add that I really need something that is able to run under Linux, because that is my main Desktop OS.

Answer (score 2):

[Orb](http://www.orb.com) may work for you.  I use it to stream Sirius to media players and my Droid.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly there is no Linux version available, which is absolutely essential for me.